# Broken utf8 conversion?

Tags: erlang

I am trying to force UTF-8 like this:

```
to_utf8(X) when is_list(X) ->
    unicode:characters_to_binary(X, utf8);
to_utf8(X) when is_binary(X) ->
    to_utf8(binary_to_list(X));
to_utf8(X) -> X.
```

And testing it like this:

```
<<"é"/utf8>> = to_utf8(<<"é">>),
<<"Ø"/utf8>> = to_utf8(<<"Ø">>),
<<"œ"/utf8>> = to_utf8(<<"œ">>),
```

When using R16B03 everything works fine. However after upgrading to Erlang 17.5, the function stopped working for characters like "œ" or "Ā" even though they are available in UTF-8

Since R17 uses utf-8 as default encoding instead of latin-1 for R16 this should work the same as before.

Did I overlooked something ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use `œ` as the example unicode character in the examples below:

```
<<197,147>>         = <<"œ"/utf8>>.
[197,147]           = binary_to_list(<<"œ"/utf8>>).
<<195,133,194,147>> = unicode:characters_to_binary(binary_to_list(<<"œ"/utf8>>), utf8).
```

Prior to R17, the default encoding of `latin1` is what allowed this to work in conjunction with [`binary_to_list/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_list-1).  The new default is `unicode`.

The list `[197,147]` is not in the format expected by the implied output encoding `unicode` in [`unicode:characters_to_binary/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#characters_to_binary-2).  If we want to use `binary_to_list/1`, we have to specify that the output encoding should be `latin1` as was the default for R16 and below:

```
<<197,147>> = unicode:characters_to_binary(binary_to_list(<<"œ"/utf8>>), latin1, latin1).
```

Another solution would be to make use of [`unicode:characters_to_list/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#characters_to_list-1) instead of `binary_to_string`:

```
[339]       = unicode:characters_to_list(<<"œ"/utf8>>).
<<197,147>> = unicode:characters_to_binary(unicode:characters_to_list(<<"œ"/utf8>>), utf8).
```

A better solution would be to just use `unicode:characters_to_binary/1,2,3` directly as there is no need to convert binaries to lists:

```
<<"œ"/utf8>> = unicode:characters_to_binary(<<197,147>>).
<<"œ"/utf8>> = unicode:characters_to_binary("œ").
```